# Proving log(n!) is in Ω(n log(n))

Tags: asymptotic-complexity, proof

The total cost of our operations are: Σ(i=1 to n) log(i).

Prove that this sum is Ω(n log(n)).

I'm a little bit stuck on how to go about proving this.  I realize the summation comes out to be log(n!), since log(1) + log(2) + log(3) = log(3!) (and so forth, etc)

But then I'm stuck on where to go for a formal proof.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: try out http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ or cstheory stackexchange.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure , that it is big omega and not big O , coz I thought every log(i) , 0 <= i <= n , could be represented as O(log(n)) , so summation would give you O(nlog(n))

Answer (score 0):

your easiest attack is to argue that \sum{i=1}^{n}\log(i) < \sum{i=1}^{n}\log(n), then show your summand is independent of the index. alternately, you can show that n! < n^n, then apply properties of logs to get your answer.